# Is the Samsung Galaxy S3 interface uglified by Samsung?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-touchwiz

Some this ago I read this article [Seriously, Samsung? This is what you're calling Ice Cream Sandwich?](http://blogs.computerworld.com/19880/samsung_ice_cream_sandwich)

Is the Galaxy S3 interface Uglified as well, as described in this articles , what about Note?

Comment: Definitely ugly.

Comment: Coming from CM7 on an Atrix, agreed.

Answer (score 5):

Samsung apply their TouchWiz interface to all of their flagship "Galaxy" devices, except for the two "Google Nexus" branded devices they have made, and they are likely to carry on doing this for the foreseeable future. The Galaxy SII and Galaxy Note both have TouchWiz.

Whether it's "uglified" or not is a matter of opinion, there are benefits to having a common interface among devices and versions, that doesn't look massively different after an upgrade. Not everyone's a technophile looking for the latest and greatest upgrade, some people just want everything to look and work the same way it used to, just a bit faster and more reliably.